# Proposal to finish cleaning up the "Modes" tags - completed

Tags: discussion, tags

**Final Version as implemented.**

## Proposal

I've gone through the various tags related to [3D Viewport Object Modes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/modes.html) and with help, the [object-mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/object-mode) and [edit-mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edit-mode) tag wiki entries are consistent with each other and with the manual.  As of 2.93 there are 7 other modes, and I'd like to propose making tags consistent for each of them.  Here's my first take on this.  I'd like feedback.

- *Sculpt*: currently has [sculpt](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sculpt) with no tag wiki entry.  I propose changing that to [sculpt-mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sculpt-mode) if possible and making the entry consistent.
- *Vertex-Paint*: currently has [vertex-paint](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vertex-paint) with no tag wiki entry. I propose changing that to [vertex-paint-mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vertex-paint-mode) if possible and making the entry consistent.
- *Weight paint*: currently has no mode tag.  I propose adding [weight-paint-mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weight-paint-mode) and making the entry consistent.
- *Texture paint*: currently has [textures](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textures) as a synonym for [texturing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texturing).  I propose adding [texture-paint-mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texture-paint-mode) and making the entry consistent.
- *Particle edit*: currently has no tag.  I propose adding [particle-edit-mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-edit-mode) and making the entry consistent.  (Note: particle edit *mode* is about things like combing hair and isn't a general particle meta topic.)
- *Pose*: currently has [pose-mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pose-mode).  I propose no change, but I've submitted an edit to make the full entry consistent.
- *Draw*: currently has [drawmodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawmodes).  This one is problematic, because it is being used for a wide range of drawing topic, but draw-mode is specific to grease pencil.  I propose adding [draw-mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/draw-mode) and making the entry consistent. *Clarification:*  As part of the overhaul of Grease Pencil, newer versions of Blender no longer rely on grease pencil tools in other modes but now has a separate mode (that I would have called grease pencil) that the developers decided to call *draw mode*.  This is like Pose mode in that it is specific to one subset of Blender things, in this case Grease Pencil.

By "making the entry consistent" I mean using boilerplate text for both the user guidance and long description, along the lines of

> Use this tags for questions about operations performed on objects when they are in MODENAME-mode, rather than any of the other modes, such as edit, sculpt and weight painting.

for the user guidance (replacing 'sculpt' or 'weight painting' in their cases)

and

> Blender has different tools available for manipulating objects in the [3D Viewport](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/modes.html) editor, depending on what [mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/modes.html) the object is in.  One of these is *MODENAME* mode. The manual describes MODENAME mode as

> [insert the manual entry for MODENAME]

> This tag should be used for questions that are specifically about the operations that can be performed on an object when it is in object mode.

Comment: Thanks for all the recent efforts cleaning up all the tags and writing up wikis. Looks like your picking up Ray Mairlot's work

Comment: You're welcome.  I wouldn't say 'picking up', as much as 'helping', at least I hope it's helpful.  I have a certain amount of time / day for Blender Stack Exchange.  If I can't find questions to answer, I spend it trying to be helpful in small ways.

Comment: Something helpful, great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of these I'm fine with others I have doubts because they are not areas of Blender I'm very familiar with.

1. Sculpt: as far as I know all sculpting in Blender is made in sculpt-mode so I suppose this one is fine to make a synonym from sculpt to sculpt-mode
2. Vertex-Paint: Since we have [vertex-colors](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vertex-colors) for non paint mode questions I suppose it is fine as well.
3. Weight paint: There are more ways to interact with vertex weights than through paint, live vertex groups or modifier. Are all Weight paint questions really related to Weight paint mode, do we really want to do this? Not disagreeing, just an area I'm not so familiar with.
4. Texture paint: This one I disagree, texture may have many meanings in Blender, from image textures, procedural textures, texture nodes, modifier/particle legacy textures, texture painting. Not only should [texture-paint](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texture-paint) coexist with [texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texture), since they are not necessarily synonyms, texture painting may also happen through the image editor, and as far as I know that doesn't require being in paint mode, or does it?
5. Particle edit: this one is fine I think
6. Draw: Draw is another meta-tag I think, it is very ambiguous on its own. Is it pertaining to drawing with grease pencil, or the annotation tool? Bezier curve drawing? Programming lingo GPU drawing, perhaps viewport shading modes? Currently we only have [drawmodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawmodes), I think the tag draw should not exist at all, and [drawmodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawmodes) should probably be renamed and turned into a synonym of something along the lines of [viewport-shading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewport-shading). Either we make [draw](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/draw) a synonym of [draw-mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/draw-mode), or [grease-pencil](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grease-pencil) or [annotation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/annotation).

Let us know what the rest of the community thinks.

Comment: About 3: It seems to me that the other ways to interact with vertex weights aren't usually thought of as 'painting', and, as far as I know, the only way to 'paint' vertex modes is in weight paint mode.  About 6: I should clarify the proposal.  As part of the great grease pencil overhaul, instead of relying on tools in other modes to do grease pencil drawing there's now a mode dedicated specifically to it.

Comment: Regarding 6, should we make draw a synonym for grease-pencil?, or should it be for drawing-mode? Then have a separate tag for annotation tool and rename drawmodes to viewport-shading?