# Custom Filter with Tags and Operators?

Tags: support

Is it somehow possible to create a custom filter that only shows certain tags, but at the same time only shows unclosed questions?

I would like to save a filter that contains the following search query:

`[geometry-nodes] or [geometry-nodes-fields] answers:0 closed:no is:question`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use filters much myself, so I may be wrong, but I don't think you can save filters that complex.

One alternative is to bookmark a custom search in your browser, which through URL allows more complex search patterns.

One example would be questions tagged [geometry-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry-nodes) or [geometry-nodes-fields](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry-nodes-fields) `answers:0` `closed:no`

[https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=[geometry-nodes]+or+[geometry-nodes-fields]+closed%3Ano+answers:0](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgeometry-nodes%5D+or+%5Bgeometry-nodes-fields%5D+closed%3Ano+answers:0)

You can add this to your browser bookmarks or setup an alias for it

`https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=[geometry-nodes]+or+[geometry-nodes-fields]+closed:no+answers:0`

On a side note I think [geometry-nodes-fields](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry-nodes-fields) tag should be removed and made a synonym of [geometry-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry-nodes). I don't think there's any point in keeping a dedicated tag just for that, since the use of fields basically implies geometry nodes.

Comment: Haha, so simple, and I of all people do not come up with this idea! :D Thanks, problem solved (with workaround)!

Comment: Side note: Well, this may sound reasonable from the point of view of an inexperienced user, but from a technical point of view these are already two different topics. This is similar to `curves` and `bezier-curves` or `model` and `modeling` ( and `modelling`), or `nodes` and `node-editor`. I think the tag should remain.

Comment: Maybe we can make a new meta post with a community poll and see what outcome we get. I'm not very knowledgeable in that area. Can one use Fields outside geometry nodes as standalone? It is my understanding they only work when geometry nodes are involved, so having a separate tag for that seems redundant to me.

Comment: Yes, let's discuss that. Are you creating a meta post?

Comment: I have a faint idea of having discussed those already. See if this addresses your concerns https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2840/proposal-to-finish-cleaning-up-the-modes-tags-completed