# Should the tag [geometry-nodes-fields] be a synonym of [geometry-nodes]?

Tags: discussion

[Duarte Farrajota Ramos](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/users/19307/duarte-farrajota-ramos) made an [interesting suggestion](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2973/145249) in a post that is worth discussing:

> "I think [geometry-nodes-fields](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry-nodes-fields) tag should be removed and made a synonym of [geometry-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry-nodes). I don't think there's any point in keeping a dedicated tag just for that, since the use of fields basically implies geometry nodes."

Personally, I am not quite sure which decision should be made here. I support both views, because for me the subject matter is quite different, but of course *Geometry Nodes Fields* are a part of *Geometry Nodes*.

What are your opinions on this? What should happen to the tag?

Should it stay or continue as a synonym?

...I have suggested the tag once as a synonym and ask for your input.

> Please be so kind and cast your vote [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tags/geometry-nodes/synonyms).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggested merging the tags [geometry-nodes-fields](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry-nodes-fields) and creating a synonym between [geometry-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry-nodes) because as far as I can tell they are not standalone, and one cannot use Geometry Nodes Fields without using Geometry Nodes in general.

Any question about Geometry Nodes Fields implies it is also necessarily about Geometry Nodes in general.

Conversely the opposite may not be true, not all Geometry Nodes questions touch fields, but despite being introduced at a later time, Fields are now an integral part of Geometry Nodes in general, and used naturally as part of a larger workflow, I don't think they need a separate specific category.

I'd vote for merging because I don't think Fields deserves a dedicated tag, I suppose no one would be specifically searching for a posts forcefully with/without fields, that filtering by [geometry-nodes-fields](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry-nodes-fields) alone would benefit anyone.

Mentioning *Fields* in the body of a question should suffice both for searching purposes and to get relevant solutions if your problem does involves fields.

Comment: ...I think the same then applies to [tag:particle-nodes] and [tag:particle-edit-mode], because these topics are not possible without [tag:particles].

Comment: Yes, some serous tag maintenance is overdue indeed. There are several other topics that don't deserve a separate tag, though I'm not sure about those particle ones. Not all particle editing is done through [tag:particle-edit-mode], a lot is done through parameters, and we have legacy particles that don't use nodes, so I don't know about those specifically. I'm not very up to date about particles though, so I'm not sure about this. It would deserve another topic

Comment: If you have any pros for keeping a dedicated [tag:geometry-nodes-fields] tag around please do post them in an answer, so the community can weight in. Also still waiting for your answer over at moderators election post. ;)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that I should write a direct answer to this :D ...I would be interested in principle, and would stand for election. However, as you know, I'm quite limited to *Geometry Nodes* and I'm not always available. ...I'm not sure if I can be of much help here. What do you think?

Comment: There are no "moderation quotas", you dedicate whatever time you can. Also being proficient in all areas of Blender is not a requirement, not even something most users would be able to reasonably do.

Comment: Regarding [tag:geometry-nodes-fields]: No, actually there are no real advantages to having your own tag. In my experience, it's mostly questions about specific node constellations or setups. In the rarest cases a question was explicitly related to fields, but that still falls under [tag:geometry-nodes]. A sub-tag would basically just be confusing and would not bring any concrete benefits ...that's my opinion. But let's see how it's voted.

Comment: Was that right to suggest a synonym for [tag:geometry-nodes] at [this link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tags/geometry-nodes/synonyms) and wait for a vote, or should that be done here?

Comment: Never used that linked form, wasn't even aware of it. I'd say let's give it a try to learn how it actually works, suggest away for the sake of science. Otherwise posting here is fine as well, and actually preferred if it is controversial or at least requires discussion

Comment: I don't think this works well at all. Apparently, the voting seems to be completely lost in this link, because it does not appear anywhere active. I'll add the link to the question...

Comment: Indeed it seems to only create a list of synonyms in the corresponding tag pages where people can vote, but there is no notifications anywhere. You only see it if you visit the tag page, so visibility is really poor. I'll merge the tag anyway